# Problems with .rosinstall when calling wstool merge

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Linux 14.04, ROS Indigo.

I am familiar with wstool. Just expanded my repository to better organize code: https://www.github.com/birlrobotics

Trying to do the traditional steps:

- wstool init
- wstool merge [address]
- wstool update

Now, when I try westool merge with the following file:
wstool merge https://github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter/blob/master/birl_baxter.rosinstall

I get the following error:

```
ERROR in config: Invalid multiproject
yaml format in
[https://github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter/blob/master/birl_baxter.rosinstall]:
mapping values are not allowed here  
in "<file>", line 7, column 19
```

A few points here:

- It does not seem that the line 7, column 19 points to anything I can figure out.
- I have tried going over this file multiple times trying to figure out if there are any small mistakes and I can't find anything.
- If I just copy the contents of the file into a local birl_baxter.rosinstall file and then call `wstool update` IT WORKS. The output below is obtained with `wstool info` if I copy the contents manually:

> workspace:
> /media/vmrguser/sdd/ros/indigo/birl_baxter_ws/src
>
> Localname                    S SCM
> Version (Spec) UID  (Spec)  URI
> (Spec) [http(s)://...]  ---------
>
> - --- -------------- -----------  ---------------------------  birl_baxter_wiki               git
>   master         bba17767ba05
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter.wiki.git
>   birl_sensors                   git
>   master         68002e8ab082
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_sensors.git
>   birl_baxter_worlds             git
>   master         89a310a39f9e
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_worlds.git
>   birl_baxter_vision             git
>   master         ac6b6776b216
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_vision.git
>   birl_baxter_tools              git
>   master         c96785268756
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_tools.git
>   birl_baxter_recorded_motions   git
>   master         ed05ddf0e0af
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_recorded_motions.git
>   birl_baxter_msgs               git
>   master         3fb7faa7bb38
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_msgs.git
>   birl_baxter_matlab             git
>   master         9cf0165b4f8c
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_matlab.git
>   birl_baxter_images             git
>   master         383a8c428bdf
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_images.git
>   birl_baxter_hands              git
>   master         6d88ca03a51b
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_hands.git
>   birl_baxter_executive          git
>   master         839f854ab3a2
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_executive.git
>   birl_baxter_examples           git
>   master         b99fb7e3bc37
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_examples.git
>   birl_baxter_demos              git
>   master         84f109b8f308
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_demos.git
>   birl_baxter_controllers        git
>   master         a5914da2a7ec
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_controllers.git
>   birl_baxter_common             git
>   master         769c4676a999
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter_common.git
>   birl_baxter                    git
>   master         45717b2422fd
>   github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter.git

Does anyone have an insight into this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249273/problems-with-.rosinstall-when-calling-wstool-merge/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2016-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are fetching the HTML page, not the raw .rosinstall file.
Use the following URL and it should work fine: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter/master/birl_baxter.rosinstall

You get this by clicking the `RAW` button at the top of the file on github.

If you use `wget PATH` you can see what you have as input to `wstool`

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyawadhwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/109959/bhavyawadhwa/) on 2022-07-05**:
perfect, thanks it works for me

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Now, when I try westool merge with the following file: wstool merge https://github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter/blob/master/birl_baxter.rosinstall

That won't work, as you're not merging the file, but the Github HTML rendering of that file in your repository.

Try:

```
wstool merge https://github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter/raw/master/birl_baxter.rosinstall
```

note the `raw` in there somewhere.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1